# Magento 2 installation stuck

Tags: magento2, php-7, vagrant

When trying to install Magento 2, the installation is currently stuck at 49% "Installing user configuration". I have tried changing the "vendor" directory to 777 as recommended by a couple of others here, though this hasn't worked. Is there anything else I can try?

For reference, I am using PHP7.0.7 on Ubuntu. Any other information needed to assist in answering, please comment.

[image]

Comment: will you please check the console for the error ? also for basic setup this blog may help . https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-setup-macosx/

Comment: @webkul The console for the install just states "Installing user configuration", and has been for about 30 mins now. The link you provided is for setup on MacOSX. I am using Ubuntu. I have read the link anyway and am unsure how it can help here.

Comment: Please share the screenshot of the console

Comment: @webkul Screenshot added.

Comment: Few questsion for debugging 
* you are using vagrant or installing in local setup - ( share the link of vagrant file which you are using make sure it support for php 7.0.7)
*You are installing it via composer ? or via complete zip downloaded from magento site ? 
* You are getting any error at browser console ?

Comment: @ wickywills Take fresh folder with composer.json available in your existing Magento root and install it through composer. I have faced same problem with my Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments under my question, I managed to complete a successful install of Magento 2 when installing it through composer.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else is having the same problem, most likely the max_execution_time is exceeded while the script runs. This can be confirmed by checking the response of the "start" request in the console (will be a 500 error) and the log file in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Just edit your php.ini and set the value from the original 30 seconds to something like 360 seconds.

The php.ini that you are using can be found using `phpinfo()` (php) or `php --info` (cli).

Restart your server and it should work fine.

Comment: 500 error is caused by a code error, and not by a timeout. If max_execution_time is the problem, then there would be a gateway timeout error 504

Answer (score 0):

I never could get passed "Installing user configuration..." (49%) when using the installation wizard, even after meeting all the requirements.

It installed in seconds without any error by using the command line install

`magento setup:install`

with all parameters, as described [in the documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html).