# Is there a way to stop an installation in progress?

Tags: magento2, installation

I'm trying to set up a new Magento 2.3 instance and I got stuck at 93%. I found through  [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119558/magento-2-installation-stuck/211550) that my max_execution_time was set to low. So I fixed that, but now I want stop the installation. I can't restart the server because there are other sites on the server. What else could I do? I'm using plesk lightsail which is Ubuntu and php 7.2. [image: screenshot of output]

EDIT: Just as a side note one of the reasons this kept hanging up was I trying to use the sample data, which was just not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just drop the partially installed `M2 database` and created the new `M2 database`
2. Remove `app/etc/env.php`
3. Start the installation again, it will create `env.php` again.

Comment: awesome, thank you so much. After I try this I'll update!

Comment: This worked and the instructions were clear, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove all files and drop the database and create it again.
Run the process again as you did in the beginning.

Comment: The reason I was asking is because I tried just removing files, and it broke ( like http 500 error) broke.

Comment: Yeah, you can't just remove the files as the DB will have something in it from the last install.
So you must delete the database name you used and then create it again.
And go with the install process again.